# Regex Including the next occurence of word

Tags: php, regex

The regex works perfectly but the problem is it also include the next occurrence instead of ending with the first occurrence then start again from the

**Regex :** `(?=<appView)\s{0,1}(.*)(?<=<\/appView>)`

**String:** `<appView></appView> <appView></appView>`

But my problem is it eat matches the whole word like

> `(Match 1)<appView></appView> <appView></appView>`

I want it to search the group differently but i cant make it work.

> *Desired output : (Match 1) `<appView></appView>`  (Match 2)`<appView></appView>`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\s{0,1}` equals `\s?` You need to use `(.*?)` to be lazy instead of `(.*)`

Use this pattern: `~(?=<appView)\s?(.*?)(?<=</appView>)~`

[Demo Link](https://regex101.com/r/m8NvYn/1)

*note, you don't have to escape `/` in the closing tag if you use something other than a slash as your pattern delimiter.  I am using `~` at the beginning and end of my pattern to avoid escaping.

Comment: This worked. I  wasted 3 hours trying to solve this. You saved me.

Comment: @ReyanTropia Don't go away. Let's talk this out.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Are you capturing? validating? replacing?

Comment: Trying to create a parsing engine for the framework im developing

Comment: For the simplest and most stable cases, this may work without a hiccup, but Sumurai8 is correct in principle -- In many cases regex is a poor tool for parsing XML.  Can you expand your question (without revealing your entire project) to explain the variability of your strings, the functions that you are calling, and the expected output?

Comment: <appView></appView> will be replaced by its contents. i.e have `<div>Hello</div>`.  A class will declare its *selector* and its content, and these contents will be placed in that <appView></appView>. Very similar to how angular components work. But i think no functions will be called

Answer (score 0):

I fully recommend to switch from regex to an actual sequential xml parser. Regex is aweful for parsing xml based files, for example because of the problems below.

That said, you can "fix" your regex by using `([^<>]*)`. This will match all characters without `<` or `>`, which will make sure that no other tags are nested inside. If done with all tags, you cannot match something like `<appview><unclosedTag></appView>`, because it is invalid. If you can be certain that the structure is correct, this is slightly less of an issue.

Another problem your approach has is that if you have nested tags like so: `<appView> something <appView> something else </appView> else </appView>`, your approach will make you end up with `[replaced] else </appView>`.

Comment: The content inside the <appView></appView> wont matter. This will be replaced by the component holding its content. I'm trying to create a php framework similar to components of angular

Comment: Except that it really does matter. I have edited my answer to showcase another problem with your approach. Your approach is naive, which will come and bite you in the long run. If you are building a framework, parse the structure once and manipulate the tree instead. It is more robust, and a lot faster if done for a larger number of tags.

Comment: Which parser do you recommend to start with? I'll take a look